# Git describe conditional fatal error in FOR /F command

Tags: git, batch-file, git-describe

This is a weird one. The code below works as expected inside a batch file:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=-" %%G IN (
    'git describe --long --always --dirty --broken'
) do (
    set tag_name=%%G
    set versions_from_tag=%%H
    set hash=%%I
    set dirty_broken=%%J
)
```

When I try to add the --abbrev option I get a fatal error:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=-" %%G IN (
    'git describe --long --always --dirty --broken --abbrev=8'
) do (
    set tag_name=%%G
    set versions_from_tag=%%H
    set hash=%%I
    set dirty_broken=%%J
)
```

outputs:`fatal: --dirty is incompatible with commit-ishes`

but if I run the command outside of the FOR /F it works as expected:

```
git describe --long --always --dirty --broken --abbrev=8
```

outputs `2.11-13-ga03306e6-dirty`

I'm assuming this probably has something to do with the environment of the `FOR /F` command?

Comment: try to escape equal sign, `… --abbrev^=8'` see

Comment: see https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: @elzooilogico yep that was it. feel free to answer. If not I'll write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to elzooilogico.

As detailed [here](http://%20http://robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php), the `=` needs to be escaped like `^=` when used in the subject of the `FOR /F` command.

Without the escape I think the 8 was being treated as the commit-ish string.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=-" %%G IN (
    'git describe --long --always --dirty --broken --abbrev^=8'
) do (
    set tag_name=%%G
    set versions_from_tag=%%H
    set hash=%%I00
    set dirty_broken=%%J
)
```

Worked as expected.